# How do I find out that ReadFile function timed-out?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, timeout, readfile

When I do not set timeout settings via GetTimeout & SetTimeout after I connect my USB-UART converter to my laptop, the ReadFile becomes blocking. However, once I set them via SetTimeOut, the ReadFile is not blocking anymore and returns true even if the given number of bytes were not read.

When ReadFile returns true but the dwRead parameter says 0 since no data was going into my PC via serial port, I conclude that the ReadFile function must have timed out. However, using GetLastError returns 0. How can I be verify in my C++ program that the ReadFile has actually timedout?

Comment: Did it transfer any bytes?

Comment: *When ReadFile returns true but the dwRead parameter says 0 [...] I conclude that the ReadFile function must have timed out* - for a serial port handle, I believe this is a safe conclusion.  If there were any *other* reason, the call would have failed.

Comment: OK, I will use that in my program. At this time I have only the USB-UART converter connected to my laptop, there is no device on the other end of the coverter so data is being read in.

Comment: the best way use ZwReadFile. and check iosb.Status - final status of operation. and work with asynchronous handles, without blocking wait

Comment: how are asynchronous handles supposed to help here? basically, PC sends a "serial command" to device I am designing and expects a response within some 100s of ms. If no response comes PC says "error: please check connection to device". I need to know how to check timeout condition for this reason.

Comment: main - in this case you never becomes blocking. ZwReadFile return STATUS_PENDING. when operation completed - looking for iosb.Information (number of bytes readed) and iosb.Status - final status of operation. in case timeout Information will be 0 and Status != 0

Comment: @RbMm: there are some situations in which using the kernel API from user mode is excusable.  This isn't one of them.  The Win32 API supports asynchronous I/O perfectly well.

Comment: ZwReadFile - this is both user and kernel mode API, and better in use then ReadFileEx

Comment: @RbMm: using ZwReadFile from a Win32 application is unsupported.  Just because you prefer the unsupported API doesn't make it an appropriate choice.

Comment: using ZwReadFile from a Win32 application is fully supported, ntdll.dll is only dll in user mode like kernel32,etc. and in case ZwReadFile - all what we need check for STATUS_TIMEOUT. when ReadFile - lost this status.

Comment: @RbMm: OK then, please point to the Microsoft documentation stating that this is "fully supported".

Comment: @HarryJohnston are supported and work only what in documentation ? for example i remember time when in documentation written then divers can be written only on c (but not on c++) and build only with make files (but not in VS). really we can free use ntdll.dll export like from any another dll. what you say - only religious taboo - nothing more. unsupported you say - but in what problem use it ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston when i post self answer i really at begin very good understand then got only minus for this. but however done from principle and because sure that this solution is the best. this situation very good show advantage of NT api over win32 api - NT return correct code for timeout - STATUS_TIMEOUT and no any problem here at all. but win32 api - lost this status(It does not distinguish it from the 0). and as result confusion and problems. so i describe root of problem and native solution. but of course almost nobody will be use this in self coding

Comment: @RbMm: the unnecessary use of unsupported APIs is cowboy programming, it's just a very bad idea.  What if the API changes or goes away in a future release of Windows?   All your code will stop working.  If you want to do it this way yourself, nobody's going to stop you.  But you're giving out bad advice.  (Nobody's going to stop you doing that, either, but that doesn't mean we can't point out to everybody else that it's bad advice.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston  if the API changes or goes away in a future release of Windows - api like ZwReadFile very well documented in MSDN and one of the 'root' in windows. it not go away or changed. in this case same can say and about ReadFile. but main my goal - describe root of problem - why in using ReadFile hard determinate timeout - because this api LOST information returned from ZwReadFile (and this is common case for win32 API). and many tools may be you know (like for example Sysinternals utilities) wide used NT api and prefect work. all this worked how minimum from win2000 up to latest win10

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think it makes no sense to conduct a philosophical discussion here. from a purely technical point of view - you understand what I wrote (about STATUS_TIMEOUT and LOST it in ReadFile api) and have an objection ?

Comment: @RbMm: from a purely technical point of view, no useful information has been lost.  Remy's answer addresses this already.  You simply don't *need* to see the STATUS_TIMEOUT.  It's an implementation detail, the programmer doesn't need to know about it, so it is not a sensible answer to this question.  (It might be a sensible answer to a question about the internal implementation.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - lost. and we need see STATUS_TIMEOUT. this is not internal and undocumented details. however how i view disscussion have no sense. sorry

Comment: @RbMm: I don't understand why you feel that we need to see the STATUS_TIMEOUT.  The OP seems perfectly happy with Remy's answer.  But I agree that there is no point in debating it any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `SetCommTimeouts()` with `ReadFile()`, the [`COMMTIMEOUTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190.aspx) documentation says:

> *ReadIntervalTimeout*
>   The maximum time allowed to elapse before the arrival of the next byte on the communications line, in milliseconds. **If the interval between the arrival of any two bytes exceeds this amount, the `ReadFile` operation is completed and any buffered data is returned**. A value of zero indicates that interval time-outs are not used.

If a timeout occurs, the read is complete (`ReadFile()` returns TRUE), and the number of bytes that had been buffered before the timeout elapsed is reflected in your `dwRead` variable. So, you will know if a timeout occurred if `dwRead` is *less than* the number of bytes you asked `ReadFile()` to read.  If there was no buffered data, `dwRead` will be 0.  If `dwRead` is *equal to* the number of bytes you asked for, there was no timeout since `ReadFile()` exited when the last requested byte was read.

Comment: Very good. Strange design, *nicht war*? Compare `read()`: it blocks until at least one byte is transferred or end of stream or an error occured, including a timeout. No nonsense about timeouts *between* bytes, which makes the timeout value very difficult to establish usefully.

Comment: `read()` can deal with timeouts between bytes, setting a reading timeout can cause it to fail with an `ETIMEDOUT` error code, same with a blocking `recv()`. I think an alternative design for `ReadFile()` would have been for it to fail with an `ERROR_TIMEOUT` error code.

Comment: `read()` cannot deal with timeouts between bytes, as it will have returned the first bytes received before the timeout. The timeout can only occur *before* receiving any bytes.

Comment: but if use NT api, like NtReadFile - you will got iosb.Status == STATUS_TIMEOUT on timeout - and this is simplest and  most accurate way

Answer (score -4):

most simplest and accurate way use NT api NtReadFile and check final status of operation. timeout <=> iosb.Status == STATUS_TIMEOUT. kernel32 api ReadFile - lost info for this status(STATUS_TIMEOUT), because it check only for STATUS_PENDING and 0 > status

for synchronous work, can use code like this:

```
void SyncTest(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_ALL_ACCESS, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        SERIAL_TIMEOUTS st = { 4000, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
        status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS, &st, sizeof(st), 0, 0);
        DbgPrint("time %x[%x,%p]\n", status, iosb.Status, iosb.Information);
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            UCHAR buf[256];
            status = NtReadFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, 0);
            DbgPrint("read %x [%x,%p]\n", status, iosb.Status, iosb.Information);
            //assert(status == iosb.Status);
            if (status == STATUS_TIMEOUT)
            {
                DbgPrint("timeout\n");
            }
        }
        NtClose(hFile);
    }
}
```

for asynchronous:

```
class __declspec(novtable) IoObject 
{
    friend class UserIrp;
protected:
    HANDLE _hFile;
private:
    LONG _dwRef;

protected:
    virtual ~IoObject()
    {
        if (_hFile) NtClose(_hFile);
    }
    virtual void OnIoComplete(NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR Information, ULONG code, PVOID pv) = 0;
public:

    NTSTATUS BindIoCompletion();

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    IoObject()
    {
        _hFile = 0;
        _dwRef = 1;
    }
};

class UserIrp : public IO_STATUS_BLOCK
{
    friend IoObject;

    IoObject* _pObj;
    PVOID _pv;
    LONG _dwRef;
    ULONG _code;

    static VOID WINAPI OnComplete(NTSTATUS Status, ULONG_PTR Information, UserIrp* This)
    {
        This->_pObj->OnIoComplete(Status, Information, This->_code, This->_pv);
        This->Release();
    }

    ~UserIrp()
    {
        _pObj->Release();
    }

public:

    NTSTATUS CheckStatus(NTSTATUS status)
    {
        if (NT_ERROR(status))
        {
            OnComplete(status, Information, this);
        }

        return status;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    UserIrp(IoObject* pObj, ULONG code, PVOID pv) : _pObj(pObj), _dwRef(1), _code(code), _pv(pv)
    {
        pObj->AddRef();
    }
};

NTSTATUS IoObject::BindIoCompletion()
{
    return RtlSetIoCompletionCallback(_hFile, (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)UserIrp::OnComplete, 0);
}

class MySerial : public IoObject
{
    void OnIoComplete(NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR Information, ULONG code, PVOID pv)
    {
        DbgPrint("OnIoComplete(%x, %p, %.4s, %p)\n", status, Information, &code, pv);

        switch (code)
        {
        case 'time':
            if (0 <= status)
            {
                if (PUCHAR buf = new UCHAR[256])
                {
                    if (UserIrp* Irp = new UserIrp(this, 'read', buf))
                    {
                        static LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset;
                        status = Irp->CheckStatus(NtReadFile(_hFile, 0, 0, Irp, Irp, buf, 256, &ByteOffset, 0));
                        DbgPrint("read begin = %x\n", status);
                        return ;
                    }
                    delete buf;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'read':
            DbgPrint("read end(%x, %p)\n", status, Information);
            if (status == STATUS_TIMEOUT)
            {
                DbgPrint("timeout\n");
            }
            delete pv;
            break;
        }
    }

    virtual ~MySerial()
    {
        DbgPrint("--MySerial<%p>\n", this);
    }

public:

    MySerial()
    {
        DbgPrint("++MySerial<%p>\n", this);
    }

    NTSTATUS Open(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        return NtOpenFile(&_hFile, FILE_ALL_ACCESS, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0);
    }

    NTSTATUS SetTimeouts(ULONG ms)
    {
        if (UserIrp* Irp = new UserIrp(this, 'time', 0))
        {
            SERIAL_TIMEOUTS st = { ms, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
            return Irp->CheckStatus(ZwDeviceIoControlFile(_hFile, 0, 0, Irp, Irp, IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS, &st, sizeof(st), 0, 0));
        }

        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
};

void AsyncTest(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    if (MySerial* p = new MySerial)
    {
        if (0 <= p->Open(poa) && 0 <= p->BindIoCompletion())
        {
            NTSTATUS status = p->SetTimeouts(4000);
            DbgPrint("set timeout=%x\n", status);
        }
        p->Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: There sure are a lot of ways of doing things here

Comment: @quantum231 use native api most accurate way - simply need check final NTSTATUS of operation. in your case - this will be STATUS_TIMEOUT. not need check byte count, GetLastError, etc